# MySql: Relation between Diseases and Symptoms

Tags: java, mysql, many-to-many

I'm working on a Spring Boot App project, which works with diseases and symptoms. So i'm thinking, if a disease can have more symptoms, and also, a symptom can be linked to more diseases, that means i'll have a many-to-many relation in MySql. Also, a symptom can be a general symptom for one disease, and a specific symptom for another (each disease has it's general and specific symptoms). Does this mean i have to have TWO many-to-many relations between diseases and symptoms?

And i'm not certain i really need for each symptom to have a list of diseases where it is a general symptom, and a list where it is a specific one.

I'm pretty new to MySql, so i was wondering if this is the most optimal solution. Any input would be appreciated:

```
@Entity
public class Disease implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private DiseaseGroup group;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "disease_generalSymptoms",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "disease_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "symptom_id") })
    private ArrayList<Symptom> generalSymptoms = new ArrayList<Symptom>();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "disease_specificSymptoms",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "disease_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "symptom_id") })
    private ArrayList<Symptom> specificSymptoms = new ArrayList<Simptom>();
}

@Entity
public class Symptom implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "symptom")
    private ArrayList<Disease> diseasesWhereThisIsAGeneralSymptom = new ArrayList<Disease>();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "symptom")
    private ArrayList<Disease> diseasesWhereThisIsASpecificSymptom = new ArrayList<Disease>();
```

}

Comment: My take is that at this moment, your question is more about database design rather than how do I code this up in Java with Hibernate.  If so, then you should focus on trying to nail down a table design first with primary and foreign keys.

Comment: Yeah - it looks like you're starting at the wrong end of the lollipop.